# jQuery Show and Hide Content

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a vertical `accordion` menu on the left and once a user clicks on a menu item, the content displays on the right. I am trying to get it so when the user loads the page, there is already content on the right.  The content area is currently blank.  How can I have content on the right and then when the user clicks on a menu item the content is replaced with new content.

I am very new to jQuery. This is my first project. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

The display on the jsfiddle is not exact, but you should be able to get the idea.

The link to the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsuni5/fmj6gkj0)**

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you provided what you tried and isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably simplest way:

```
$('#section-whicheveryouwant').show();
```

Add that to end of your `$(document).ready` function.

Also - I recommend putting all your `$(document).ready` inside your closure - or don't use the closure - just be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you already tried triggering the click on the first element on page load. It's not triggering that event however, because the selector is incorrect. In the line where it says

`$('#cssmenu topics:first a').trigger('click');`

it should say:

`$('#cssmenu .topics:first a').trigger('click');`